# How to authenticate into Mongodb using Node JS driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I already have created a user that has the proper roles to readWrite the database following this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-secure-mongodb-nosql-production-database/. I can login to the user using my username and password from both the command line (mongosh) and using the GUI (mongodb compass). However I can't figure out how to authenticate using Node JS. Every time I try it says

```
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
  ...
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: "AuthenticationFailed",
  connectionGeneration: 0
```

My current code is based on the Mongodb docs https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/authentication/mechanisms/

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const myMongo = new MongoClient(`mongodb://${encodeURIComponent(username)}:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@localhost:27017`);
myMongo.connect();
```

The encodeURIComponent is necessary to avoid `MongoParseError: Password contains unescaped characters`. All examples on Google of how to do this use mongoose or some other wrapper library, but I don't want to use a wrapper. I've tried specifiying the authMechanism but it changes nothing. The rest of the URL is correct because it worked before I setup authentication. The username and password are also correct because they work in both mongosh and compass. The only do not work in Node JS.

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "vxsacademy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cd src; node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.6",
    "bson": "^6.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: add the `package.json` file to your question.

Comment: Try to escape only the password, not the username.

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My package.json's dependencies are
```
{
    "bson": "^6.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^6.1.0"
}
```

I originally was not escaping the password and it was not working. I then escaped the username as well because the docs said to and it continued to not work.

Comment: add the full file to your question.

Comment: @xgqfrms I don't think any of the other info in package.json is relevant but I added it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

### solution

1. You should set the `authMechanism` in the connection string.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("MongoDB");

const authMechanism = "DEFAULT";


const username = encodeURIComponent("your username");
const password = encodeURIComponent("your password");
const clusterUrl = "localhost:27017";

const uri = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@${clusterUrl}/?authMechanism=${authMechanism}`;

const myMongo = new MongoClient(uri);

myMongo.connect();
```

2. If the username or password includes the following characters:

```
$ : / ? # [ ] @
```

those characters must be converted using [`percent encoding`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1).

[image]

### refs

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/authentication/mechanisms/

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: When I use your code I get `MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number`. When I use the Standard Standalone connection string instead I get the same `MongoServerError: Authentication failed.` even though I specified the `authMechanism`. I am percent encoding the username and password using encodeURIComponent.

Comment: But it's not a percent encoding issue because it still happens when I use a username and password that doesn't require encoding. `mongodb://testuser:aaa@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT`. It works in mongosh though. `vxsacademy> db.auth("testuser", "aaa")
{ ok: 1 }
vxsacademy> db.getUser("testuser")
{
  _id: 'vxsacademy.testuser',
  userId: new UUID("aa512c97-01ca-4206-ad9d-3ce5af418fee"),
  user: 'testuser',
  db: 'vxsacademy',
  roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: 'vxsacademy' } ],
  mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
}`

Comment: try change `mongodb+srv`  to `mongodb`.

Comment: That is what I just tried and it did not work. But after doing some testing it seems that other computers on my local network can't actually connect to the database. At this point I've tried everything I can think of to get authentication working and nothing works so I'm just going to settle on simply not requiring authentication to connect to the database. Overall I'm very disappointed with Mongodb but there aren't really any alternative document oriented databases so I guess I'm stuck with it.